# Is it possible to search an enum types list of values to see if an int exists?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, enums

say i have an enum

```
public myEnum
{
   value1, value2

}
```

if I have an integer, can I see if it exists within myEnum?

Comment: Why? This is not what enums are for. Use a list or something like that and Linq.

Comment: Sometimes I wish we could downvote comments.

Comment: enum is part of auto generated data layer, can't easily change it. It is a list of values in db reference tables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Enum.IsDefined()`. The full definition is

```
public static bool IsDefined(
    Type enumType,
    Object value
)
```

Example usage:

```
public enum MyEnum { A = 1, B = 2 };

Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), 1) --> true
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), 3) --> false
```

You can find more information [on this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx).